# Pasar dato a select en modal

Tags: javascript, html

Nuevamente acudo a su conocimiento,

tengo una tabla la cual lleno con datos desde mysql, cada fila tiene un boton que despliega una ventana modal la cual lleva los datos de la fila sobre la que se dio click en el botón. Dentro de la ventana modal tengo un elemento select el cual necesito que cargue como valor uno de los datos de la fila seleccionada, pero no funciona.

Esta es mi ventana modal

```html
<div class="modal fade mt-4" id="cliente-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cliente-modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h6 class="modal-title">Modificar Cliente</h6>
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cerrar">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <form action="" method="post" class="form-group">
                                <div>
                                    <label>Identificaci&oacuten</label></div>
                                <div><input type="text" id="identidad" name="identidad" class="data" readonly></div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="">Nombre</label></div>
                                <div><input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="data" disabled></div>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="">Correo</label></div>
                                    <div><input type="text" id="correo" name="correo" class="form-control"></div>
                             
                                <label for="producto">Producto</label>
                                <select class="custom-select" name="id_producto" id="id_producto" required>
                                    <option value=""></option>
                                    <?php

                                                        foreach($matriz_producto as $producto){
                                                        echo "<option value='".$producto["id_producto"]."'>".$producto["descripcion"] ."</option>" ;
 
                                                          }  

                                                        ?>
                                </select>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <input type=submit value="Guardar" id="guardar" name="guardar" class="mt-4 btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-guardar"></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Con esta función paso los datos a la modal

```html
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.cliente-modal', function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var nombre = $('#nombre' + id).text();
        var identidad = $('#identidad' + id).text();
        var correo = $('#correo' + id).text();
        var producto = $('#id_producto' + id).text();

        $('#cliente-modal').modal('show');
        $('#nombre').val(nombre);
        $('#identidad').val(identidad);
        $('#correo').val(correo);
        $('#id_producto').val(producto);
    });
});
```

Así lleno la tabla que pasa los datos a la modal

```html
<blink>    <table class="table table-striped tablesorter" id="tabla">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Identificacion</th>
                        <th>Producto</th>
                        <th>Modificar</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </thead>
                    <?php foreach($consultaClientes as $datos): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span id="nombre<?php echo $datos->getCodigo(); ?>"><?php echo $datos->getNombre() ?></span></td>
                        <td><span id="identidad<?php echo $datos->getCodigo(); ?>"><?php echo $datos->getIdentidad() ?></span></td>
                        <td><span id="id_producto<?php echo $datos->getCodigo(); ?>"><?php echo $datos->getProducto() ?></span></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm cliente-modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cliente-modal" value="<?php echo $datos->getCodigo(); ?>"><span>Modificar</span></button></td>
                        <td style="display:none;"><span id="correo<?php echo $datos->getCodigo(); ?>"><?php echo $datos->getCorreo() ?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                        endforeach;
                        ?>
                </table>    </blink>
```

De antemano gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Acabo de probar tu codigo y funciona bien.

Comment: En efecto funciona pasa todos los campos de la tabla al modal pero no carga el valor en el elemento select . Al desplegar la ventana modal el select se ve vació por defecto y lo que necesito es que tome el valor correspondiente

Comment: A mi me funciono tambien con el select.  Que pasa si haces un `console.log(producto)` te imprime el valor correcto? Ese valor esta presente en las opciones del select?

Comment: Adicione el console.log(producto) pero al inspeccionar la consola no trae el dato.

Comment: Eso quiere decir que no esta leyendo nada con `$('#id_producto' + id).text();`  Si agregas el codigo de como generas las filas quizas podamos encontrar el error.

Comment: @alanfcm edite la pregunta inicial y agregue el código con el que lleno la tabla como me lo indicaste

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta en esta linea:

```
var producto = $('#id_producto' + id).text();
```

Estas seleccionando el texto del select y luego tratas de buscar el valor con ese texto, pero ese valor no existe.  La forma correcta seria asi:

```
var producto = $('#id_producto' + id).val();
```